# Django: How to use XMLHttpRequest in cache's key

Tags: django, caching, xmlhttprequest

I have a URL that returns the same content but with different templates depending on 
`request.is_ajax()` value.

How can I include this in the cache's key parameter, so I cache the correct response according to it?

I tried using vary_on_headers decorator with 'XMLHttpRequest', but it did not work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `vary_on_headers` requires you to specify the actual headers to check, and "XHMLHttpRequest" is not one of them. Django looks for that value *in* the `HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH` header, so that's the one you need to vary on.

Comment: Just to make clear for others that may use this. you have to use vary_on_headers('X_REQUESTED_WITH') and not vary_on_headers('HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'), since the middleware already adds 'HTTP_' to it